# Call a method in Tomcat every 2 hours

Tags: tomcat

I want to call parsePage() method every 2 hours, the method will process the page and update the information in database. I want to put this in a Tomcat server and my code looks like this right now:

```
TimerTask parserTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyParser.parsePage();
    }
};

Timer parserTimer = new Timer();
parserTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(parserTimerTask, 0, PERIOD);
```

I put this in class(that load on start up)'s init() method.

Am I doing this correctly? Or is there better way to do this task?

Thanks.

Comment: If you decide to stick with doing it inside tomcat, have a look at Quartz, an easy to use scheduling library.  It's been around for a long time and is still maintained and still free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should work.

You'll obviously also need to create a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and pass the TimerTask to the appropriate schedule method in order to kick off the execution of the TimerTask in a repeated manner, something like:

```
Timer timer=new Timer(true);
timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 0, 2*3600*1000L);
```

In more sophisticated environments, you might want to look at using something like the [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). This will give you things like better logging, redundancy failover, more sophisticated schedules, transaction control etc. But all this probably isn't necessary for a simple use case.

Comment: Yes I do have a timer and scheduled it, I edited my OP. Thanks for your respond.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much information here but it might make more sense in a linux environment to use a cron job to call curl or wget to a servlet?

Comment: I'm running Tomcat on a EC2 instance w/ Ubuntu. I've never thought of this way, this makes more sense and I will look into it, thanks!